# Small part bed adhesion

Tags: prusa-i3, pla, heated-bed

I am trying to print a model that has (at the start of the print) several small parts attached to the bed. Some of these parts have bed contact 2.5mm x 20mm.

After a few layers, if there are any imperfections in the previous layer, the hotend is bumping the imperfection and knocking the part loose.

I am using a genuine Prusa i3 Mk2s with Filaform PLA. I am slicing with PrusaControl and using the "Generic PLA" settings, which is giving me 215/210 degree hot end (first/other layers), and 55 degree bed. I have the fan enabled. The print bed is clean and dust free

How can I improve bed adhesion for these small parts, ideally without adding brims etc?

Thanks

Comment: I also found out that using wet screen wipes to remove any residue from touching works really well for increasing bed adhesion.

Comment: Do any of the answers helped you to get an answer on your question or helped you come to your own conclusions then please do vote and accept an answer. This helps us reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered). Found an other answer (then the already posted) yourself? Please add that answer (and accept after 48 hours) to share your experience with the community. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to add your own custom brims to the model. A couple of "Mickey Mouse ears", attached to each end of the piece, may be enough to keep it in place (and will also be easy to remove).

Answer (score 2):

First off, in my experience 215 °C printing temperature is very high for PLA. Try using 200 - 205 °C.

And whatever you are printing, I can't see why brims would be a problem. Use a sharp knife to remove them afterwards. As you described the parts are thin and long, which increases heat contraction. Brims are essential for this.

Comment: Thanks, I will give both of these a try. 215 degrees C is the PrusaControl settings.

Comment: Do remember that there is such a thing as "High temp PLA" that needs to be printed at 215 or above. Normally the packaging or on the website it will tell you the needed print temp. So it could also be the right temp.

Comment: @Granny that is very well possible, thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

My low-tech solution is to smear on some school/craft glue-stick. This is so quick and so easy yet it has saved me so many times from going any further troubleshooting adhesion problems.

My [answer to a similar question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5781/9719) describes this in full.

Comment: I asked the similar question :) thanks for the info

Comment: @AndrewP, did you give it a go yet? I know it sounds almost too easy, but it works brilliantly.